# How to run AVD with Internal Storage only like android Moto G is having?

Tags: android, storage, internal

I want to create an emulator in Eclipse which only runs on Internal Storage. More in that I want to put image in Emulator so That it comes up in Gallery when i run My AVD. How can i do that can Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GenyMotion for creating various devices. Its much more flexible, faster and when compared to emulator and you can work with many other features like Google Maps etc. Just for info